# regex code to extract html between 2 comments in vb.net not working

Tags: regex, vb.net, html-parsing

I'm trying to extract a portion of html between 2 comments.

here is the test code:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim base_dir As String = "D:\"
    Dim test_file As String = base_dir & "72.htm"

    Dim start_comment As String = "<!-- start of content -->"
    Dim end_comment As String = "<!-- end of content -->"

    Dim regex_pattern As String = start_comment & ".*" & end_comment
    Dim input_text As String = start_comment & "some more html text" & end_comment 

    Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(input_text, regex_pattern)


    If match.Success Then
        Console.WriteLine("found {0}", match.Value)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("not found")
    End If

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

The above works.

When I try to  load actual data from disk the below code fails.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim base_dir As String = "D:\"
    Dim test_file As String = base_dir & "72.htm"

    Dim start_comment As String = "<!-- start of content -->"
    Dim end_comment As String = "<!-- end of content -->"

    Dim regex_pattern As String = start_comment & ".*" & end_comment
    Dim input_text As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(test_file).Replace(vbCrLf, "") 

    Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(input_text, regex_pattern)


    If match.Success Then
        Console.WriteLine("found {0}", match.Value)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("not found")
    End If

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

The HTML file contains the start and end comments and a good amount of HTML in-between.
Some content in the HTML file is in Arabic.

With thanks and regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/284240

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing in `RegexOptions.Singleline` into `Regex.Match(...)` like this:

```
Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(input_text, regex_pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

This will make the Dot's `.` match newlines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `vb.net`, but does `.` match newlines or is there an option you have to set for that? Consider using `[\s\S]` instead of `.` to include newlines.